# Instagram API returning results out of the given radius

Tags: geolocation, instagram-api

I'm using the Instagram API and giving a longitude, latitude and radius.
Except relevant results from that location, I seem to be getting few (like 1) results from outside that radius, sometimes in a different continent.

Is it possible Instagram is returning results that they consider relevant to that geo area or something? Is that a known issue?

Example query:
42.698, 23.322
5km

And i'm using the /media/search endpoint

I tried using Apigee.com to stimulate that query but they seem to be returning partial results:
https://apigee.com/snapshot/instagram?snapId=apigee-console-snapshots-1422766800000_058d16ec-932d-4c21-ad26-354fba9abf63

(I get like 900+) results, not 14-15

Thanks..

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't reproduce that behavior by using those coordinates.  Can you be more specific about how you consistently get that situation?